# Filling a deck of cards and printing a random card from the deck C#

Tags: c#, arrays, random

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    
    string[] cardDeck = new string[52];
    string[] numbers = { "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen",    "King" };
    string[] suites = { "Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Spades" };
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < suites.Length; j++)
        {
            cardDeck[i + j] = numbers[i] + " of " + suites[j];
            Console.WriteLine(cardDeck[i + j]);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("The random card is " + RandomCard(cardDeck));
}

static string RandomCard(string[] deck)
{
    Random card = new Random();
    int index = card.Next(0, deck.Length);
    return deck[index];
}
```

I am having difficulty printing the RandomCard. Sometimes it prints a card and other times it doesn't. Did I fill my card deck correctly? How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: `cardDeck[i + j]` is wrong - they should be more like `cardDeck[i*4 + j]` - the 4 because there are four suits.

Comment: Side note: you should limit code to just a problem you have - there is no need to include that quite wrong  `RandomCard` if you have problem with initializing the array. (I assume you do know how to properly use `Random` as you've read [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=net-7.0#avoiding-multiple-instantiations)). I'd recommend to re-read the [mre] guidance to improve future questions.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov you are quite the champion of friendliness. I think you are the one who possibly haven't read the docs on Random, and definitely haven't read the post we are discussing here. OP's program just needs to generate one single random number in its whole lifecycle and it is a very simple console app, so it makes no difference if he instantiates a Random object or not to generate this single value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Introduce a third index variable `k` in order to track the position of the cards in your deck. You can increment the variable along with `j`, i.e. inside the inner for loop, each time you place a new card into the deck:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] cardDeck = new string[52];
    string[] numbers = { "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };
    string[] suites = { "Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Spades" };

    int k = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < suites.Length; j++)
        {
            cardDeck[k] = numbers[i] + " of " + suites[j];
            Console.WriteLine(cardDeck[k]);
            k++;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("The random card is " + RandomCard(cardDeck));
}

static string RandomCard(string[] deck)
{
    Random card = new Random();
    int index = card.Next(0, deck.Length);
    return deck[index];
}
```

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77491504/filling-a-deck-of-cards-and-printing-a-random-card-from-the-deck-c-sharp/77491542#comment136613648_77491504) proposed by @500-InternalServerError of using `[i*4 + j]` will also do the job, but since you have 3 arrays modeling 3 collections of data, I think it is only natural to use 3 indexes as well.

---

EDIT: Explanation of how it works, as requested in the comments.

1. In the outer `for` loop, we loop through the 13 numbers, from Ace to King. This means that the index `i` will take values from 0 to 12.
2. using another nested for loop, for each of the numbers (i.e each value of `i`) we loop again 4 times, each time corresponding to a suit. This means that the index `j` will take values from 0 to 3. In each iteration of the inner loop, we will have a different combination of `i` and `j`, that make a unique card, so it's in this point that we store the card inside the array `deck[]`. The total amount of unique combinations is 13*4 = 52.
3. Then, there is the completely separated array `cards[]` of 52 positions to fill, where we just want to place the 52 generated values sequentially. For this reason, the index `k` will take values from 0 to 51. Note that, since there are 52 cards, the inner loop will execute exactly 52 times. This means that if we increment `k++` inside of the inner loop, we will traverse the `deck[]` from 0 to 51, increasing `k` by 1 each time the inner loop is executed.
4. Finally, we pick one single card from the deck choosing a random position by using `RandomCard(string[] deck)`

Comment: Can you explain to me how this works?

Comment: @iLuvSoftware sure, I added an explanation to the best of my abilities, I hope it helps.